# How can I execute a function with promises and check its value multiple times by API call and execute another function with the value?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I'm working on an app where I need to make an API call which is in a function then use its value to make another API call. But the first API call's value is not readily available as it depends on some external factors. So after making the first API call I need to make 3 API calls in 5 second intervals to check if the value is available or not. If it is then make the second API call else don't make the second API call.

Now I know I have to do this Promises and I tried doing it but I'm not sure if what I'm doing is right.

This is what I could do about the Promise function:

```
const promiseFunc = ( param1, param2 ) => {

     return new Promise(( resolve, reject ) => {
           
          const func1 = api1( param1 );

          if ( func1.code === '200' ) {
      
                const startInterval = setInterval( () => {
 
                       const check = getValue();

                              if ( check && check === param2 ) {
                                    clearInterval( startInterval );
                                    resolve();
                               } else {
                                    reject();
                               }
                       
                }, 5000);

          } else {
                reject();
          }

     });

}
```

So what is happening in the above func is that it takes two parameters for calling the api calls.
`func1` is executed and if it returns 200 then start the interval timer. Please note that `api1` function call is the API call. I tried using await there but it throws error. And I'm not sure if I can use async/await inside a Promise function.

Moving on, `check` variable starts making api calls (`getValue()` is also a function which includes the api endpoints) to check the value if it is available or not. if it is then resolve, if it doesn't then reject.

Here's how I'm executing the promiseFunc in sequence:

```
promiseFunc( myChosenValue1, myChosenValue2 )
     .then( data => {
            return promiseFunc( valueFromFirstExecution1, valueFromFirstExecution2 )       
     })
     .then( () => {
           console.log( 'Successfully executed both the functions' );
     })
     .catch( e => {
           console.log( e );
     });
```

This is the farthest I could go in writing a Promise function and I know there are multiple issues in the above code. The first function gets executed properly but then I get this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'code' of undefined`. Also, I'm not sure if the API calls in setInterval would run. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

So you have a couple of things going on here:

1. You want to *poll* a server-side process for completion
2. You want to call another function with the result of the successful completion of the server-side process.

So lets write some helpers:

```js
// We need a way to wait for some amount of time before
// retrying a request, sleep sleeps for n milliseconds
const sleep = (n) => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, n));

// We need a unique sentinel value so we know when we have actual
// results from an API call instead of this default value
const sentinel = {}; // or Symbol, whatever unique you prefer

// poll will take the data necessary to make a fetch
// request and repeat it every `interval` milliseconds
// up to `maxRetries` until it gets a result
const poll = async (url, fetchOpts, interval, maxRetries) => {
  let result = sentinel; // default value
  let ticker = 0; // current number of retries
  while (result === sentinel && ticker < maxRetries) {
    // make the api call
    const resp = await fetch(url, fetchOpts);
    const data = await resp.json();

    // do we have a result?
    if (isDone(data)) { // whatever criteria == completion
      result = data; // breaks the loop
    } else {
      // wait `interval` milliseconds and try again.
      ticker++;
      await sleep(interval);
    }
  }

  // Oops! We didn't get an answer back from the
  // api in time
  if (result === sentinel) {
    throw new Error('Exceeded maxRetries!');
  }

  return result;
};
```

So now we can actually do the thing we want:

```js
// call this with the eventual result, *if* we
// get one
const onSuccess = (result) => {...}; // whatever

// This is doing the actual work
const doTheThing = async () => {
  await fetch(firstApiCall); // kick off the process
  try {
    // wait for completion
    const data = await poll(url, {}, 5000, 6); // ~30sec timeout

    // pass successful result onwards
    return onSuccess(data);
  } catch (err) {
    // Error bubbling is a little weird with async
    // functions, so we'll just handle it here and
    // return undefined
    console.error(err)
    return
  }
};
```

Comment: Sorry mate. It's going way over my head. If you could explain a bit, it'd be a big help.

Comment: @s.khan if i understood what you wanted correctly, you want to 1. use an api request to start some process on your (or someone else's) server 2. keep making another api request until you get back the result of the thing you kicked off with (1) 3. if you get it back pass the result to another function. Is that accurate?

Comment: Yes. If I get the result from the first function, then make the same api call as the first one but with different parameters.

Comment: @s.khan Ah ok. That doesn't really change the answer though, just instead of calling some function (like the one I named 'onSuccess') you'll just make the first API call again with the `data`). I just added some more comments, let me know if it's still unclear.

Comment: Hey man. Thanks a lot for your time. However, I'm trying to understand one issue. The fetch func in poll, is this the  same as this ```const check = getValue();``` ? Or it is the same as ```const func1 = api1( param1 );```?

Comment: Yes. I was just using the browser fetch function to indicate where you would make an api call.

Comment: Hey. I have been trying out your code and testing for the last 4 hours. But I'm not sure if the ```const check = getValue();``` is being triggered after every 5 seconds. Shouldn't sleep function recall ```poll``` function every 5s recursively?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238951/discussion-between-jared-smith-and-s-khan).